# Role of ?+.+ in select statement in HiveQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have some HQL code which I am trying to understand.
Below is the code.

```
FROM (SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 FROM t1)
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t2
SELECT `(col_1)?+.+`
```

Can someone explain how does this ?+.+ work ? and what is the keyword to refer to this type of construct in sql/hql ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution.
The select statement is just using a regular expression, so in this case

SELECT `(col_1)?+.+`

will select all columns except col_1

Reference Doc: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select

Comment: That is right. If you want to execute the query in hive you would have to set the next variable too: ``` set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none; ```